# Filter Gravity Forms Entries By Date

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to filter (show) Gravity Forms Entries on the front end of my site between two certain dates. One being today (the current present date) and a custom date added within the backend of the website.

So only entries that were submitted between the custom date and the present date.

I have two variables storing these dates:
`$new_start_date` is the custom date, and 
`$end_date` is the present days' date.

My code is outputting 200 entries but some of which are before the custom start date.

Below is my query code:

```
<?php
//Get the Form ID to get the entries from and store it within a varibale
$form_id = GFAPI::get_form(2);


// Get Dates
$date_page_id = get_field( 'update_dates_page_link', 'options', false, false );           
$start_date = get_field( 'oak_submission_date', $date_page_id ); // date of the last submission date
$end_date   = date( 'Y-m-d', time() ); //get today's date   

// Convert start_date to match end_date format
$new_start_date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd/m/Y', $start_date );
$new_start_date = $new_start_date->format( 'Y-m-d' );


    $search_criteria = array(
        'status'        => 'active',
        'start_date'    => $new_start_date,
        'end_date'      => $end_date,
        'field_filters' => array(
            array(
                'key'   => '53', // Trust name field
                'value' => 'Oak Trust',
            ),
            array(
                'key'   => '49', // Grant Made field
                'value' => 'No',
            ),
        ),
    );  
    $sorting = null;
    $paging  = array( 'offset' => 0, 'page_size' => 200 );

    $entries = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria, $sorting, $paging );
```

// Code that outputs to the screen

```
foreach ( $entries as $entry) :

    echo '<li>';

    echo 'ID: '. $entry[68] .' : ' . $entry[2] .' : Submission Date: '. $entry[54];

    echo '</li>';

endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

`GFAPI::get_form(2)` doesn't return the Form ID it returns the Form. Try this:

```
$entries = GFAPI::get_entries( 2, $search_criteria, $sorting, $paging );
```

Answer (score 0):

Get entries of date wise filter Ex:

```
    $search_criteria               = array();
    $form_id                       = 79;//Form ID
    $start_date                    = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year') );
    $end_date                      = date( 'Y-m-d', time() );
    $search_criteria['start_date'] = $start_date;
    $search_criteria['end_date']   = $end_date;

    $results = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria );
    var_dump($results);
```

More information https://docs.gravityforms.com/searching-and-getting-entries-with-the-gfapi/